# how to learn number of repeater fields in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have about csv dataset contains 50k data. Count denotes number of tags. I want  result as a1 =130 (100+20+10), a2=50, a3=30, a4=30

Dataset:
Tags, Count
a1,100
a1-a2,20
a2-a3-a4,30
a1,10

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exploded_tags = df[['Tags']].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['Tags'].split("-")),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
df_exploded = df.merge(exploded_tags.rename('exploded_tags'), left_index=True, right_index=True)
results = df_exploded.groupby(['exploded_tags']).sum()
```

Comment: I received error "can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>"

Comment: You can try exploded_tags.to_frame() instead of using rename function.
`df.merge(exploded_tags.to_frame('exploded_tags'), left_index=True, right_index=True)`